# loop over many urls using requests.post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I Have a list like this for example (I have 100 urls):

```
https://google.com
https://facebook.com
https://yahoo.com
https://stackoverflow.com
```

Saved in **cisco.txt**
I made this script in python to make a post request on every url and give me the response but it just request one url so I want to loop over each url

```
import requests
import ssl
import sys
with open('cisco.txt') as fp:
   for line in fp:
      print(line)
   request =(line) 
    
   data={'SAMLResponse':'test'}
   response = requests.post(request, data, verify=False)
    
   print(response.content)
```

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it all in the loop. Currently the last line will set the request and only then you start making your one request.

```
import requests
import ssl
import sys

with open('cisco.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
        request =(line) 
        # keep all of this in the loop
        data={'SAMLResponse':'test'}
        response = requests.post(request, data, verify=False)
        print(response.content)
```